# php cURL , fill a remote form

Tags: php, curl

is it possible to fill a remote form with the desired data ?

**Remote form**

```
<input type=text name=uploads[0] id=attachId0 size=30 onchange="checkUploadFile(this);"><input type=button value="del" id=idAttachOper0 onclick="return delInput('idfilespan','0')"><br id=idAttachBr0>
```

Comment: Yes. You may want to pose a more elaborated question. See [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`](http://pt.php.net/curl_setopt).

Comment: Depends on your definition of 'fill a remote form' you can remotely submit the form or you can request the contents of the page, and inject a value (so the displayed URI displays as the script calling cURL). But you can't actually physically populate certain fields on a form (unless for some reason the form self populates certain fields after a failed POST atttemp).

Comment: Hi all- I'm working on something very similar to what you have here and was wondering if you had a solution. Please share your experience with me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925442/how-to-use-curl-to-post-form-values-on-form-using-js  THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to know where that form sends its data before you can send it, because you will have to emulate a form. cURL has the ability to send POST and GET data to the server via many different option settings. check out [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for all the settings. Anything that start with CURLOPT_POST... is a good bet.